# CMD command- user name

Tags: windows, cmd

I am a newbie to CMD commands, and I really appreciate any help in this regard. I am making a CMD command to delete one certain file in the C drive with the following path: C:\Users\Alaska\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Platformnew\platformX

Now, what should I replace my machine's user name (Alaska) with to get this CMD command to work on any machine (with other usernames) that install my platform?

Thanks in advance for your tips :)

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways you might be able to do this:

```
 "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\~..."
```

Or you can cut the C:\Users out with (Better, as works with Vista + and older XP, 98 style C:\Documents and Settings\

```
 "%Userprofile%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Platformnew\platformX"
```

Or you can use %AppData% to get the roaming appdata folder:

```
 "%AppData%"
```

for the path `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: For the OP - use double quotes around the entire `"path\filename"` when there are spaces or `&` characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the variable that is being set by the system:`%username%`

```
rd "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Platformnew\platformX"
```